# Cannot See Desktop After 12.04 to 12.04.1 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 12.04.1 LTS through the Update Manager, I can no longer see my desktop or access any other features of OS. Not sure if my video card a/o driver is not compatible with the new release or what the problem might be. I am able to select the OS in the new GRUB, but it doesn't do much after that.

Comment: Could You be more specific when you say "I can no longer see my desktop or access any other features of OS". Is error appear or what?

Comment: Nothing appears. After entering my PW, I get a blank screen. No error. I think it is trying to display something because the monitor does not go to sleep, but nothing appears.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the recovery mode form the grub boot screen? select it and choose failsafeX option and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the recovery mode form the grub boot screen? select it and choose failsafeX option and see if that gets you anywhere. - [some guy](http://askubuntu.com/users/88110/some-guy)